# Is a conversion to the Muslim faith valid, if it happened by deadly threat?

Tags: conversion, imaan

Is a conversion to the Muslim faith valid, if it happened by deadly threat?

Thus, without the threat, the convert wouldn't have converted, because e.g. he doesn't believe that Mohamed was Allah's messenger. He only did, because if he doesn't do, he had been killed.

Is such a conversion still valid on the Sharia?

Comment: لا اکراه فی الدین
I don't think so!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To be a muslim you have to believe in it, saying something and not believing it will not make a person muslim. 
The same goes for a muslim person if  he was threatened by death or deny islam, if he does deny islam he will not be considered out of islam.

Answer (score 3):

Scholars are divided over coercion into Islam.

Those scholars like ibn kathir, Abdul Aziz bin baaz who say pagans can be forced to Islam base their view on Quran 9:5. They say 9:5 abrogates 2:256( no compulsion in Religion). Ordinary muslims can't force pagans to Islam at present. Declaration of Jihad by a ruler/ amir ul mumineen is absolute precondition to forcing pagans to Islam.

> 9:5 And when the sacred months have passed, then kill the polytheists wherever you find them and capture them and besiege them and sit in wait for them at every place of ambush. But if they should repent, establish prayer, and give zakah, let them [go] on their way. Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.

Another instance from hadith where non pagans will also be forced to Islam is during reign of Eesa bin Maryam.

> Eesa will abolish Jizya (bukhari 2222)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, that's not how belief/disbelief works.  While it may be possible for a human to force someone to e.g. pray, it is not possible to force someone to believe, i.e., become a Muslim.

> **There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion.** ... [Qur'an 2:256](http://quran.com/2:256)

There's many fatawa confirming this, e.g.:

> If one whom it is not permissible to compel is compelled to enter Islam, such as a dhimmi (non-Muslim living under Muslim rule) or a non-Muslim who has been granted security, **he is not deemed to be a Muslim unless he shows signs of having become Muslim voluntarily**. -- [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/178756)
>
> **...sincerity is one of the conditions of accepting Islam.**  -- [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/128862)

The idea of someone being forced into Islam also goes against:

> And **it is not for a soul to believe except by permission of Allah**, and He will place defilement upon those who will not use reason. -- [Qur'an 10:100](https://quran.com/10/100)

Likewise, one does not stop being a Muslim if coerced to "convert" to another religion:

> Whoever disbelieves in Allah after his belief... **except for one who is forced [to renounce his religion] while his heart is secure in faith**. But those who [willingly] open their breasts to disbelief, upon them is wrath from Allah , and for them is a great punishment; -- [Qur'an 16:106](https://quran.com/16/106)

which is also confirmed in the fatwa:

> al-Mawsoo‘ah al-Fiqhiyyah: **The fuqaha’ are unanimously agreed that if a person is forced to disbelieve and utters the word of disbelief, he does not become a disbeliever thereby.** -- [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/150748)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is absolutely invalid. The person who is under threat may be forgiven from Allah SWT; but the person who is threating to others to accept it, is doing wrong as per the instructions of Islam. He would be punished for this action. You have to convince through arguments and if someone really accept this, he/she is welcome, if not still we have to love and respect him/her and pray for him/her.